# JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I consume a Web API in the MVC project I encountered this error, but I cannot fix it. How can I solve this?

My API is clearly working but MVC implementation doesn't work.

```
Controller

public async Task<IActionResult> ListCountries()
    {
        List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
        HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage _response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        _client = _apiHelper.Initial();
        _response = await _client.GetAsync("api/Countries/getall");
        if (_response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var results = _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(results);
        }   

        return View(countries);
    }

JSON Data

"data": [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "countryName": "Afghanistan"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "countryName": "Albania"
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "countryName": "Algeria"
 }
]
```

Comment: What's your actual response? What you've posted isn't valid JSON. What's the definition of `Country`?

Comment: I send the data into JSON format. Just it

Comment: An example of a valid response would be `{ data: [{"id": 1, "countryName": "Afghanistan"}] }` (mind the opening `{`). This would not deserialize into a `List` because it isn't one; it would deserialize into a type with a `data` property of type `List<Country>`. You could use something like `.DeserializeAnonymousType(response, new { data = default(List<Country>) }).data` for that, or declare a new class.

Comment: Thanks. Can you write the full syntax?

Comment: I Have Some Array Data Come From API Json Format, I want to convert array type to List. There is a MVC project and I used the list in Index Page. How Can I deserialize the array format to list?

Answer (score 0):

If you built the Web Api change its response from

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "countryName": "Afghanistan"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "countryName": "Albania"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "countryName": "Algeria"
}]
```

To

```
 [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "countryName": "Afghanistan"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "countryName": "Albania"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "countryName": "Algeria"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the object and cast it from json response to object

```
public class Data
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string countryName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Data> data { get; set; }
    }
```